# USRP B200 C# API

Tags: c#, usrp, uhd

i am new to SDR, and i have a task for writing a program to search for bluetooth devices, using the USRP B200. Preferable language is C#. The problem is that there is no API for C# from Ettus themselves (only C, C++, python), and the only API that i have found (https://github.com/Shkarlatov/uhdsharp) lacks the ability to change bandwidth (function does not change the value in the SDR), which is stuck at 54MHz.
So, my question is, is there any other c# API? Or, probably, could you share yours, if you have done such a thing? That would be much appreciated, as i checked manuals on c++ api for UHD, and they horrify me.

Comment: There are different bandwidths.  Either software or hardware isn't support the bandwidth.  See : file:///C:/Users/jwarburg/Downloads/usrp-software-defined-radio.pdf

Comment: You can pinvoke from c# to a C/C++ dll.

Comment: @jdweng, i tried to set up rate of 4MHz with bandwidth of 4MHz as well, also experimented with different bandwidths, but none of them worked.

Neil, i can, but i am not able to do it due to my bad knowledge of c++.

Comment: What happens if you try to change from 54MHz to 54MHz?  Changing from same rate will indicate if you are having a software of hardware issue.  The hardware on your PC may not support the rates of the BlueTooth device.  The Blue tooth specification has different versions and it is possible the PC hardware isn't fully compatible with the external device.

Comment: I would not trust a wrapper that has not been updated in the last 3 years and has only one star. 
You would need anyway to inspect it, and it would mean C++ anyway.

Don't be afraid of it, you don't need the entire language I suppose.

Comment: @changing to 54MHz leads to nothing - no error or anything. Also my task is to analyze Bluetooth with the usrp, and it should be possible to do, as usrp has much greater specs than needed.

Comment: @VincenzoLaSpesa, i have recently dipped into the sources of the wrapper, but it seems alright, at least, there is no obvious reason for this particular function not to work, as it is wrapped just as others. Also the initial code has some links to the files, which i cannot find in the UHD anymore, even in the required version, so i don't really think that i can fix that API. At least not with the limited time i have